# Dynamic textfields in UITableViewCell loses its data when scrolled

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I know this question has many answers already, but not got the solution of my problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";//[NSString st ringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UITextField *textField_Name, *textField_PhoneNumber;
 UIButton *button_AddToMyCon;

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    if (indexPath.row < rowcount-2) {

    textField_Name = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    textField_PhoneNumber = [[UITextField alloc]init];

    textField_Name.frame = CGRectMake(10, (cell.frame.size.height-20)/2, 143, 30);
    textField_PhoneNumber.frame = CGRectMake(167, (cell.frame.size.height-20)/2, 143, 30);

    textField_Name.delegate = self;
    textField_PhoneNumber.delegate = self;

    textField_Name.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    textField_PhoneNumber.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    textField_Name.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Link Name" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];
    textField_PhoneNumber.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Web Link / URL" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}];

    textField_Name.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    textField_Name.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [textField_Name.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
    [textField_Name.layer setBorderWidth:0.5];
    textField_Name.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:15.0];


    textField_PhoneNumber.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    textField_PhoneNumber.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [textField_PhoneNumber.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
    [textField_PhoneNumber.layer setBorderWidth:0.5];
    textField_PhoneNumber.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:15.0];
    textField_Name.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(152.0f/255.0f) green:(152.0f/255.0f) blue:(152.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
    textField_PhoneNumber.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(152.0f/255.0f) green:(152.0f/255.0f) blue:(152.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
   // textField_Name.tag=501+indexPath.row;
        textField_Name.tag = ktagName;
    NSLog(@"textField_Name.tag %ld",(long)textField_Name.tag);
    //textField_PhoneNumber.tag=701+indexPath.row;
        textField_PhoneNumber.tag =ktagPhn;
    NSLog(@"textField_PhoneNumber.tag %ld",(long)textField_PhoneNumber.tag);
    if(intEditSave == 1)
    {
        [textField_Name setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [textField_PhoneNumber setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [textField_Name setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [textField_PhoneNumber setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
        textField_PhoneNumber.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;

    [cell addSubview:textField_Name];
    [cell addSubview:textField_PhoneNumber];
    UILabel *linelable=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height+10, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 0.5)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:linelable];
    [linelable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(152.0f/255.0f) green:(152.0f/255.0f) blue:(152.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.2f]];

    }
else if (indexPath.row==rowcount-2){
        NSLog(@"indexPath.row==rowcount-1");
        UIButton*    button_AddMore = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        [button_AddMore setTitle:ktagAdd_More forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button_AddMore titleLabel].font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:15.0];
        [button_AddMore setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button_AddMore addTarget:self action:@selector(addMoreButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       // button_AddMore.tag = ktagbutton_AddMore;
        button_AddMore.frame = CGRectMake(90, (cell.frame.size.height-20)/2, 140, 30);
        [button_AddMore setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addMore_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button_AddMore];

        button_AddMore.tag=indexPath.row;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row==rowcount-1)
    {
        button_AddToMyCon = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        [button_AddToMyCon setTitle:ktagAdd_to_MyCon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button_AddToMyCon titleLabel].font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:15.0];
        [button_AddToMyCon setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button_AddToMyCon addTarget:self action:@selector(save_Fields:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button_AddToMyCon.tag = ktagbutton_AddToMyCon;
        button_AddToMyCon.frame = CGRectMake(90, (cell.frame.size.height-20)/2, 140, 30);

        [button_AddToMyCon setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(234.0f/255.0f) green:(134.0f/255.0f) blue:(59.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0]];
        button_AddToMyCon.layer.cornerRadius=4;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button_AddToMyCon];

        UILabel *linelable=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height+10, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 0.5)];
       [linelable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(152.0f/255.0f) green:(152.0f/255.0f) blue:(152.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.2f]];

    }
}
return cell;
}

-(void)addMoreButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
rowcount=rowcount+1;

int section = 0;
long row = rowcount;

NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row-3 inSection:section];

[(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:ktagtableView_detailsEdit] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:path, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

NSIndexPath* top = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowcount-1 inSection:0];
 [(UITableView*)[self.view viewWithTag:ktagtableView_detailsEdit] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:top atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];  //
//[(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:ktagtableView_detailsEdit]reloadData];

}
```

Here the scenario is that the tableview has 4 rows default each containing two textfields. And a add more button and one save button. On the click of add more button one row is added each time. Please guis for above.

Comment: Did you try to put your code outside of 
if(cell == nil)
{cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
...here...

Comment: you can call beginUpdate and endUpdate methods while inserting rows. Also you can try reload table to get back the data which is losing.

Comment: You know, there was probably a compiler warning telling you `cell` was being referenced with no value.

Comment: I tried your steps also not worked for me.What i tried is saving the value in string of textfield in cell but how to maintain the uniqueness of textfield is the major issue.

Answer (score 0):

`cell` instance doesn't have a initial value. Set it to `nil` on first line first.

A more proper way:

```
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        // add subviews to cellview
    }
    // set data to subviews
}
```